lightning-datatable Fieldset Editable
I have an LWC lightning-datatable that I am populating using a field set.
When I go to the datatable the fields are not editable.  Is it possible to make the fields editable so that I can save all the changes with a button?
Thanks
P

Can you post your code? You might just have to set column.editable = true. Or it could be a permissions issue.

Below is what I did to solve my issue
 mergeDataTableValues(your_table_data, draft_changes){
    return your_table_data.map(row => {
        let record = { 
            ...row
        };
        
        const yourDraftRecord = draft_changes.filter(draft => draft.Id === record.Id);
    
        if(draftRecord){
            record = {
                ...record,
                ...draftRecord[0]
            };
        }
    
        return record;
    })    
}

